# How to set default product sort direction (asc/desc) for few categories only through xml

Tags: php, xml, magento, magento2, magento-layout-xml

In Magento 2 how I can set default product sort direction (asc/desc) for specific categories through layout update xml of 
Manage Categories ->Specific Category-> Design section.
Like I did in screenshot... But its not working :([image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just need to change `referenceblock` name  to "`product_list_toolbar`". because we dont have **setDefaultDirection** method in Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct class. after update your code will become like this

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
  <referenceBlock name="product_list_toolbar">
          <action method="setDefaultDirection">
              <argument name="dir" xsi:type="string">desc</argument>
            </action>
  </referenceBlock>
</referenceContainer>
```

please let me know if you have any queries.

Comment: can i add this to any layout xml file to override it for all categories ?